# USB Drive No Media after I command "attributes disk clear readonly" in cmd

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I was trying to fix write protected usb drive issue and followed a tutorial (https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/the-disk-is-write-protected-windows-10.html), and my flash disk ended up being not recognizable by windows explorer and diskpart reports it as "No Media".

PS: `Windows Troubleshooter` doesn't work. Uninstalling driver and replug it doesn't work

[image: Picture]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: If you have used diskpart and by mistake erased the disk in such a manner that it can no longer even be formatted, then it might take a professional to get it working again.

Comment: Or the write-protect was the warning of an about to fail flash memory. Now it's completely dead.